# DataSet in Panda: Increase Offset if next value is smaller then previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

i have following DataSet initially:

```
value;date
100;2021-01-01
160;2021-02-01
250;2021-02-15
10;2021-03-01
90;2021-04-01
150;2021-04-15
350;2021-06-01
20;2021-07-01
100;2021-08-01
10;2021-08-10
```

Whenever the value "Value" drops (e.g. from 250 to 10 on 2021-03-01), I want to save the old value as offset.

When the value drops again (e.g. from 350 to 20 on 2021-07-01) I want to add the new offset to the old one (350 + 250).

Afterwards I want to add the offsets with the values, so that I get the following DataSet at the end:

```
value;date;offset;corrected_value
100;2021-01-01;0;100
160;2021-02-01;0;160
250;2021-02-15;0;250
10;2021-03-01;250;260
90;2021-04-01;250;340
150;2021-04-15;250;400
350;2021-06-01;250;600
20;2021-07-01;600;620
100;2021-08-01;600;700
10;2021-08-10;700;710
```

My current (terrible) approach whichis not working:

```py
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df.index = df['date']
    del df['date']
    df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

    df['previous'] = df['value'].shift(1)

    def pn(current, previous, offset):
        if not pd.isna(previous):
            if current < previous:
                return previous + offset
        return offset

    df['offset'] = 0
    df['offset'] = df.apply(lambda row: pn(row['value'], row['previous'], row['offset']), axis=1)
```

Your help is so much appreciated, thank you!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the desired positions in column 'value' with [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). Fill with 0 and compute the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). Add the 'offset' column to 'value'

```
df['offset'] = df.value[df.value.diff().lt(0).shift(-1, fill_value=False)]
df['offset'] = df.offset.shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum().astype('int')

df['correct_value'] = df.offset + df.value
df
```

Output

```
   value        date  offset  correct_value
0    100  2021-01-01       0            100
1    160  2021-02-01       0            160
2    250  2021-02-15       0            250
3     10  2021-03-01     250            260
4     90  2021-04-01     250            340
5    150  2021-04-15     250            400
6    350  2021-06-01     250            600
7     20  2021-07-01     600            620
8    100  2021-08-01     600            700
9     10  2021-08-10     700            710
```